# Custom plugin: Trying to show saved data on frontend

Tags: php, plugin-development, hooks, options, globals

I'm working on my first plugin and I have made a nice settings page which saves and works.

But I have split it to few files and now I can't determine if field is checked.. I have also tried declaring a `global` variable but I can't get it to work :\

**Plugin**

This is how my plugin starts:

```
global $if_autoload;

add_action('init', 'additional_menus_admin');

function additional_menus_admin() {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/admin.php');
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/hooks.php');
}
```

**hooks.php**

Here I try to see if the `"autoload"` checkbox is checked:

```
add_action('wp_head','hook_additional_menu', 20);

function hook_additional_menu() {
    global $if_autoload;

    echo '<test>'.$if_autoload.'</test>';

}
```

**admin.php**

I have also tried using the [`get_option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) function but nothing changes. All the fields are being save on my `admin.php` file and I tried pushing the `global` variable from there too:

```
function menu_autoload_callback() {
    $if_autoload = get_option( 'autoload-or-shortcode' );
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="autoload-or-shortcode" value="1"'. checked( 1, get_option( 'autoload-or-shortcode' ), false ) .' /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a headache and make a class. The static variable can be accessed like a global once it's loaded. Just be sure the class exists before you try to use it!

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WPSE_20150123_Plugin' ) ) {

    class WPSE_20150123_Plugin {

        // our variable that will be set and read back later
        public static $if_autoload = 'I\'m Not Sure???';

        // 'init' hook
        public static function init() {

            // show value
            echo static::$if_autoload; // I'm quite sure 
        }
    }
}

// set the static value
WPSE_20150123_Plugin::$if_autoload = 'I\'m quite sure!';

// hook init to static function
add_action( 'init', 'WPSE_20150123_Plugin::init' );
```

---

**admin.php**

Looking at your [`checked()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) function, I'm not quite sure you're using it correctly. This is the example they give and your args look like they're in the wrong place.

```
<?php

// Get an array of options from the database.
$options = get_option( 'slug_option' );

// Get the value of this option.
$checked = $options['self-destruct'];

// The value to compare with (the value of the checkbox below).
$current = 1; 

// True by default, just here to make things clear.
$echo = true;

?>
<input name="slug-option[self-destruct]" value="1" <?php checked( $checked, $current, $echo ); ?>/>
```

Your function might work better as:

```
function menu_autoload_callback() {
    $if_autoload = get_option( 'autoload-or-shortcode' );
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="autoload-or-shortcode" value="1" ' . checked( $if_autoload , 1, false ) . ' /><br />';
}
```

---

**hooks.php**

Another thing, it looks like you echo invalid html:

```
echo '<test>'.$if_autoload.'</test>';
```

should be

```
echo '<h1 class="test" >If Autoload: ' . $if_autoload . '</h1>';
```

---

It wouldn't hurt to take a look at http://wppb.me.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i used this-

```
// Define global variables
    global  $am_globals;
            $am_globals = array(
                'if_autoload' => get_option( 'autoload-or-shortcode' ),
            );
```

and this-

```
if( ! $if_autoload = $GLOBALS['am_globals']['if_autoload'] ) {
```

Comment: I think you would have done better taking the advice you asked for :)